# LEFT-JOIN instead of oracle (+) with where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

Last post got deleted because of "duplicated" posts (10 years ago), but I can't adapt the answer to my query.

I want to replace the oracle (+) with a LEFT JOIN, but I can't figure it out.

```
FROM a,b,c
WHERE b.a  = '101'
AND a.a    = '202'
AND b.c    = a.c
AND a.d    = c.d(+)
AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

What I've tried is

```
FROM a
LEFT JOIN c
ON a.d = c.d
WHERE b.a  = '101'
AND a.a    = '202'
AND b.c    = a.c
AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

but since I've never fetched the data from table b, it fails.

Comment: And JOIN the "b" table (as it is missing, but is still referenced in WHERE clause).

Comment: Hm. "move the table c condition from WHERE to ON", there is no c condition in the where clause?

Comment: How to I join the "b" table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to `INNER JOIN` to `b` and then `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to `c`:

```sql
FROM  a
      INNER JOIN b
      ON (b.c = a.c)
      LEFT OUTER JOIN c
      ON (a.d = c.d)
WHERE b.a  = '101'
AND   a.a    = '202'
AND   ROWNUM = 1;
```

---

Your query:

> ```sql
> FROM a,b,c
> WHERE b.a  = '101'
> AND a.a    = '202'
> AND b.c    = a.c
> AND a.d    = c.d(+)
> AND ROWNUM = 1;
> ```

A comma in the `FROM` clause signifies a `CROSS JOIN`.

However, in the `WHERE` clause you have:

- `b.c = a.c` which changes the join condition between tables `a` and `b` from a `CROSS JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`; and
- `a.d = c.d(+)` which changes the join condition between tables `a` and `c` from a `CROSS JOIN` to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: @klabbaparn the join syntax doesn't require brackets, also the `inner` and `outer` keywords are optional, e.g. `from x left join y on y.xxx = x.xxx` is perfectly valid.